# comment body size in hook_form_comment_form_alter

Tags: 7, comments, theming, forms

What is the correct syntax to alter the size of the comment form body text area?  I can't for the life of me find it in devel dpm.

```
$form['comment_body']....something....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`#rows`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#rows) and [`#cols`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#cols) properties to define the height and width respectively:

```
$form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#rows'] = 10;
$form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#cols'] = 50;
```

Comment: I was looking for the size.  That makes sense.  I got the rows to work with $form['comment_body']['und'][0]['#rows'] = 10; but the columns I cant get to work.  I have tried $form['comment_body']['und'][0]['#columns'][0] = 20; and $form['comment_body']['und'][0]['#columns'] = 20;

Comment: It's `#cols`, not `#columns`, it should probably be `$form['comment_body']['und'][0]['#cols'] = 20;`

Comment: That doesn't work.  comment_body > und > 0 > #cols is not there.  #rows is there, but not #cols.  #cols is at comment_body > #cols, and it doesn't work

Comment: It's probably a CSS issue, if you look in the markup you'll see the `cols` attribute on the `<textarea>` element. Try adding `.form-textarea-wrapper textarea { width: auto; }` to your stylesheet, that'll override the `width: 100%` set in the system CSS files. If you've got a WYSIWYG editor on the comment body this probably won't work, as they tend to fill the width of their container

Comment: Here is a shot of the dpm: http://i.imgur.com/12nwN.png